# Cosa significa "particolare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ci aspettavamo tutti la furia di Tobia e invece lui trovò una voce ragionativa e parlò come un avvocato. Disse: – Ha considerato Amabile che lui è **particolare** mentre io sono solo un mezzadro? Eppure gli do mia figlia, sana, tutt’altro che brutta e ancora cosí com’è uscita da sua madre, e le ho fatto quattro marenghi di dote. Amabile cosa può pretendere di piú? Sentiamo. 
>         – Dice che voi come mezzadro siete grosso e che invece lui come **particolare** ha appena un fazzoletto di terra e non della meglio che ci sia.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "particolare" in questo passaggio? Alla voce "particolare" in alcuni dizionari ho trovato che, come sostantivo, vuol dire "cittadino privato", "persona singola", ma non capisco come questo si possa contrapporre a "mezzadro".

Comment: Credo significhi che è un piccolo proprietario terriero o che lavora in proprio, al contrario del mezzadro, che invece lavora la terra del padrone.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: [Questo articolo](https://dial.uclouvain.be/downloader/downloader.php?pid=boreal:81491&datastream=PDF_01) conferma la tua ipotesi: spiega che significa “piccolo possidente”.

Comment: Ecco il passo dell'articolo sopra linkato che parla di questo e altri termini che appaiono nel romanzo:

Comment: «L’influsso 
del dialetto ha lasciato delle tracce anche nel lessico de *La malora*; Fenoglio utilizza 
“censa” invece di “privativa”, “stroppo” invece di “branco”, “onta” invece di “vergogna”, 
“particolare” invece di “piccolo possidente”, “bricco” invece di “monte”, “rubarizio” invece di “furto”, “diffizioso” invece di “schizzinoso”, “sversa” invece di “contrariata”, “alla mira” invece di “al punto”, “genare” invece di “imbarazzare”, “schivare” invece di “tener da parte” e “sbardati” invece di “sparpagliati” (tutti questi esempi secondo Grignani, 97).»

Comment: Particolare significa quindi piccolo possidente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato di ***particolare*** nel contesto da te citato è di proprietario di una [particella](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/particella/), piccolo possidente:

> particèlla s. f. [lat. **particĕlla*, dim. di *particŭla* che a sua volta
>   è dim. di *pars partis* «parte»].

e significa:

> 2. Porzione di terreno. a. P. (o parcella) catastale, l’unità catastale costituita da una porzione continua di terreno, situata in
>      un solo comune e appartenente a un solo proprietario (o a più
>      proprietarî pro indiviso), che sia di un’unica qualità o classe di
>      coltura e abbia un’unica destinazione oppure sia occupata da un
>      fabbricato con caratteristiche proprie e dalle relative pertinenze.

A differenza del mezzadro che aveva il diritto di lavorare il pezzo di terra ma non ne era il proprietario.